# replace NA value in unmatched rows after joining data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.table.

```
dt1 <- data.table(id=seq(1, 4), col1=1:4, col2=1:4, col3=1:4)
dt2 <- data.table(id=seq(1, 5), val=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
```

I want to do a right join like

```
dt <- merge(dt1, dt2, all.y=TRUE, by="id")
```

but replace NAs in the results with 0.
The result should be

```
id  col1    col2    col3    val
1   1   1   1   a
2   2   2   2   b
3   3   3   3   c
4   4   4   4   d
5   0   0   0   e
```

I have a lot of columns in the data.table so I don't want to change them one by one. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: there is [open FR](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/857) to improve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new table, you might consider just adding the cols from `dt1` to `dt2`:

```
cols = setdiff(names(dt1), "id")
dt2[dt1, on="id", (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols))]
dt2[!dt1, on="id", (cols) := 0 ]

   id val col1 col2 col3
1:  1   a    1    1    1
2:  2   b    2    2    2
3:  3   c    3    3    3
4:  4   d    4    4    4
5:  5   e    0    0    0
```

If you really want a new table, though, you can do

```
cols = setdiff(names(dt1), "id")
z = dt1[dt2, on="id"]
z[!dt1, on="id", (cols) := 0 ]

   id col1 col2 col3 val
1:  1    1    1    1   a
2:  2    2    2    2   b
3:  3    3    3    3   c
4:  4    4    4    4   d
5:  5    0    0    0   e
```

The package maintainers plan to write a vignette on joins.